# Schattenparker: Wird dieses Wort wirklich benutzt?

Tags: word-usage, usage

Eine Liste von ungewöhnlichen deutschen Wörtern wurde auf der Facebookseite von *German Embassy Delhi* gepostet, mit der Bemerkung "these words we need in English". Eines der Wörter war **Schattenparker**. Die Erläuterung erklärte es als Äquivalent zu Warmduscher. Das leuchtet ja ein, aber wird Schattenparker tatsächlich benutzt? Ich habe es noch nie gehört oder gelesen.

Comment: Ja, dieses Wort in dieser Bedeutung habe ich im umgangssprachlichen Gebrauch schon oft gehört (weniger gelesen).

Comment: I, personally, have never heard of it. As a side fact, the translations in this facebook post are only partly correct, don't take it as a learning resource.

Comment: Schattenparker ist mir auch sehr geläufig (auch wenn die Nutzung zurückzugehen scheint, aber das ist nur mein persönlicher Eindruck. Es gibt eine ganze Reihe solcher Wörter: Turnbeutelvergesser fällt mir da spontan noch ein... Es gibt ganze [Webseiten](http://www.gerstlauer.de/andreas/fun/warmduscher.html), die sich mit diesen Worten beschäftigen

Comment: Habe es hier noch nie gehört. Habe nur *Vorwärtseinparker* öfter gehört. Aber wie Volker's Antwort sagt, dass war alles eine Modeerscheinung. *Warmduscher* war, soweit ich weiß, tatsächlich der erste Begriff dieser Art: [Warmduscher in Wikipedia](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Warmduscher).

Comment: Noch nie gehört das Wort. Ich musste länger überlegen, was es sein soll, weil Schatten-Irgendwas häufiger metaphorisch genutzt wird und diese Assoziation ständig ablenkt.

Answer (score 11):

Das war eine relativ kurzlebige Modeerscheinung um 2000 herum (wenn ich das richtig in Erinnerung habe), damals entstanden eine Reihe von neuen fantasievollen und blumigen Ausdrücken für das, was vorher vor allem als "Weichei" bezeichnet wurde. "Warmduscher" müsste einer der ersten gewesen sein und hat sich bis heute gehalten (auch wenn man selbst den nicht mehr sehr häufig hört), "Schattenparker" kam etwas später und ist nur noch sehr selten zu hören - alle weiteren sind m.E. total in Vergessenheit geraten.

Comment: Andere Beispiele für diese Ausdrucksweise: Vorwärts-Einparker, Einmeter-Brett-Springer.. Gibt es einen allgemeinen Begriff für diese "abfälligen Agensnomen"?

Comment: @KilianFoth   Diese Frage - ob es einen (wissenschaftlichen?) Begriff gibt zur Bezeichnung dieser Form von pseudomaskulinöser Verunglimpfung vermeintlich Schwächerer oder vermeintlich wenig Männlicher -  wäre eigentlich eine eigene Frage in dieser Runde wert. Stellst du sie? Oder soll ich?

Comment: Der Begriff *Schattenparker* wird noch immer verwendet. Die Aussage *»total in Vergessenheit geraten«* gilt auf keinen Fall. Wenn du 10 deutsche Muttersprachler fragst, was das Wort »Schattenparker« bedeutet, werden es dir sicher mehr als 5 erklären können. Bei Wörtern, die *»total in Vergessenheit geraten«* sind, fallen mir eher diese Wörter ein: *Karzer, Kamelle, schwofen, Plumeau* oder *abgefeimt* ein.

Comment: @kilianfoth Vorwärts-Einparker hab ich noch nicht in der Bedeutung von Warmduscher o.ä. gehört. Da es deutlich schwieriger ist, vorwärts längs zur Fahrtrichtung einzuparken, steht Vorwärts-Einparker eher für Ungeschickt.

Comment: @Hubert Schölnast: Zu Schattenparker hatte ich ja auch "nur noch sehr selten benutzt" geschrieben, die Vergessenheit bezog sich auf "alle weiteren". Wobei in meinen Augen auch ein (auf Nachfrage) "ich erinnere mich an den Begriff, habe ihn aber seit 15 - 20 Jahren nicht mehr gehört" als "in Vergessenheit geraten" erfüllt. Zu Deinen Beispielen: "Plumeau" kenne ich tatsächlich nicht, kann aber eine eine regionale Frage sein. Die anderen 4 sind mir durchaus vertraut ;-)

Answer (score 7):

Ja, es wird benutzt und hat deswegen seinen Weg in die Wörterbücher gefunden:

[DWDS](https://www.dwds.de/wb/Schattenparker) - *dort auch einige Verwendungsbeispiele*
[Dict.cc](https://www.dict.cc/german-english/Schattenparker.html)
[Urban Dictionary](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Schattenparker)
[Mundmische](https://www.mundmische.de/bedeutung/3831-Schattenparker)

---

Weil es im Kommentar gefragt wurde hier ein DWDS Verlaufsdiagramm zur Nutzung seit 1995:

[image]

Dieses Diagramm ist natürlich statistischer Quatsch, da nur ganz wenige Fundstellen ausgewertet wurden (maximal 22 im Jahr 2000). Es hilft bei der Frage, ob das Wort mittlerweile weniger benutzt wird, nicht weiter.

Ich  habe zwar wie andere auch den Eindruck, aber bei diesem nicht näher zu belegenden subjektiven Gefühl muss es bleiben. Wir wissen es nämlich nicht. Vielleicht wurde es ja schon immer nur selten benutzt?

Comment: Dass es seinen Weg in die o.g. Wörterverzeichnise gefunden hat, ist noch kein Nachweis dafür, dass es wirklich verwendet wird (DWDS vielleicht ausgenommen). Manche Wörter finden Einzug in solche Verzeichnisse, besonders wenn es Jedermannsammlungen sind, nur weil jemand sie besonders interessant findet, ohne dass sie im Alltag - außerhalb metasprachlicher Diskussionen - vorkämen.

Comment: @ChristianGeiselmann: es wurde weder gefragt, ob es häufig, noch ob es selten, oder gar regional oder sonstwie benutzt wird. Es wurde nur gefragt, ob es tatsächlich benutzt wird und das kann man durch den DWDS-Eintrag mit seinen Referenzen klar belegen. Die anderen Links sind sozusagen Beigaben zur Bedeutung falls Leute das noch nie gehört haben. Ob die Verwendung nun gleich häufig, seltener, oder gar sehr viel seltener geworden ist, weiß ich nicht. Gefühlsmäßig würde ich schon sagen, dass ich es viel weniger höre, aber zählt das?

Comment: Die Eingangsfrage war "Wird Schattenparker wirklich benutzt?". Eine sinnvolle Antwort darauf kann nicht binär sein (ja/nein), sondern wird immer eine Quantifizierung enthalten: "Nein, das wird so gut wie nie benützt", "Ja, das wird sehr häufig benützt." - Ich habe mir die Funde bei DWDS kurz angeschaut. Es sind ja wirklich nur wenige Einzelfälle (aus Zeitungsartikeln v.a.). Demnach wäre meine Antwort eigentlich eher: Nee, das Wort wird praktisch im Alltag nicht verwendet. Es kommt am häufigsten in Diskussionen über eben solche Wortgebilde vor. Wie eben hier.

Comment: @ChristianGeiselmann: um zu sagen, wie selten es benutzt wird, bräuchte man eine Statistik, alles andere ist Gefühlsgeblubber.

Comment: Vor allem berücksichtigen die üblichen Statistiken ja auch nur die Nutzung in schriftlichen Texten. Das ist aber eher ein Wort, dass meistens nur im Mündlichen Verwendung findet oder fand. Das ändert aber nichts an @Takkat 's Aussage, das alles nur subjekive Einschätzungen sein können.

Answer (score 2):

[image: Schattenparker]

1. Es gibt den Sachverhalt (siehe meinen Schnappschuss von heute)
2. Praktisch jeder versteht, was damit gemeint ist

Aus meiner Sicht ist damit eine weitere theoretische Diskussion hinsichtlich der Existenz des Wortes hinfällig. Glücklicherweise ist eine Sprache da nicht limitiert. Vergleiche *Gaslaternenanzünder*, der nur noch von historischem Interesse ist und damit Punkt 1 nur bedingt erfüllt.